# Show the following is a subspace and find its dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $V=K^{2009}$ where $K$ is a field. Show $W=\{(a,b,a,b,a,b,...)|a,b \in K \}$ is a subspace and find $dim_{K}W$.

My Attempt;
For $W$ to be a subspace of $V$ two propeties must hold;
**Closure by Additivity**
**Closure by Scalar Multiplication**

For the first assume two elements of ;
$v_1=(w,x,w,x,w,x,w,x,.....)$ for some $w,x \in K$
$v_2=(y,z,y,z,y,z,y,z,.....)$ for some $y,z \in K$
The sum of the two
$v_1+v_2=(w+y,x+z,w+y,x+z,w+y,....)$ where $w+y,x+z \in K$
So closure holds.
For the second assume an element of $W$ ;
$v_1=(w,x,w,x,w,x,w,x,.....)$ for some $w,x \in K$
and a scalar $\alpha \in K$
then scalar multiplication yields,
$\alpha v_1=(\alpha w,\alpha x,\alpha w,\alpha x,...)$ where $\alpha w , \alpha x \in K$
So closure by multiplication holds.
And therefore W is a subspace.

> Find $dim_{K}W$

Now wouldn't the basis of $W$ consist of all the possible pairings of two unique members of $K$, wouldn't that be countably infinite? is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the span of the vectors $(1,0,1,0,1 \dots)$ and $(0,1,0,1,0, \dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two parameters that you are varying in your definition (your $a$ and $b$), this is a strong indication that your vector space has dimension $2$.  Now, we want to exhibit a basis of dimension $2$, so for this, think of the vectors:

$$( 0,1,0,1,\dots )$$
$$( 1,0,1,0,\dots )$$

Pay attention to the first component and second component to show linear independence, and then show that this spans the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you forgot to show that $W$ is non empty first..

$W=span\{(1,0,1,0,\dots,1)^T,(0,1,0,\dots,0,1,0)^T\},$ so $\dim W=2.$